# Why is my response data undefined when sending a fetch()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am trying to use a fetch() on my client side to post data to and from my nodeJS server.

The server recieves the post request fine and i am able to log the req variables however when i res.send('any data') the client cannot detect the data. Strangely chrome can see the response but i simply do not know how to reference the data!

Client Code

```js
fetch('/',{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
  user:{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'J@B.com',
  }
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch((error) => console.error('Error:',error))
```

Server Code

```js
app.post('/', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body.user)
  res.send('hello?')
})
```

[Chrome able to read response but data field showing undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKPoH.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `then` method takes a callback. That callback returns a value.

If that value is a promise, then it will be adopted and when it is resolved, then *next* `then` function will recieve the resolved value of that promise.

If that value isn't a promise then the next `then` function will recieve that value.

This is your function:

> res => console.log(res)

It returns the return value of `console.log(res)`.

`console.log` **always** returns `undefined`

So the next then function:

> ```
> data => console.log(data)
> ```

… gets `undefined` passed into `data`.

---

You need to return the value you actually care about.

If that value is the data in the response body, then you need to:

1. Get that data out of the body
2. Return it from the function

For example:

```
.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res.json();
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

This assumes that you get JSON back from the body. There are other methods for other kinds of data.

Comment: It's actually text

Comment: Then use `response.text()`

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains alot about my issue! i've got the issue sorted for now and i think i need to research alot more into promises (ive only recently began working with Javascript) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
then(res => res.json()) // then(res => res.text())  for converting to text
  .then(data => console.log(data));
.catch((error) => console.error('Error:',error))
```

See using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: The OP's response isn't JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not how you use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), and your first fulfillment handler is returning the result of calling `console.log`, which is always `undefined`.

In your first fulfillment handler, you need to read the body of the response (if `res.ok` is true).  For instance, to read it as text, you'd call the `text` method on the response:

```
fetch("/",{
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    user:{
        name: "John",
        email: "J@B.com",
    }
})
.then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
    }
    return res.text();
})
.then(text => console.log(text))
.catch((error) => console.error("Error:",error));
```

There are other methods on the [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) than `text`: `json`, `arrayBuffer`, `blob`, `formData`. Which you use depends on what you're sending back and what you want to do with it.

Note the check on `res.ok`. This is (IMHO) a bit of a footgun in the `fetch` API, it only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors. So you have to check for those yourself. (I describe in more in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).)

Answer (score 1):

The `res` variable is of type [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) so you need to retrieve the body as text like this:

```
fetch('/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user: {
      name: 'John',
      email: 'J@B.com',
    }
  })
})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error))
```